# Подсказки в phpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Вообщем непонятным образом отключились подсказки в phpStorm и теперь я не знаю как их включить хD

upd: и можно как то убрать значки браузеров вверху справа ?

Comment: С подсказками решен вопрос. А вот с иконками браузеров нет :(

Comment: @qweqeqwqeqr dghd, По возможности публикуйте ответы на форуме, они могут помочь многим в будущем.

Answer (score 2):

Settings/System Settings/Web Browsers, Снять галочки со всех браузеров, Apply.

Answer (score 1):

Settings -> Menus and Toolbars -> Main toolbar. Там удалять, добавлять и тд.

Answer (score 0):

На данный момент:
Настройки браузера File -> Settings... -> Tools -> Web Browsers